# How to Invert and Normalize a PIL image using the 'point-lambda' function

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

I was trying to use the `point` function to invert and normalize a `PIL image` to 1;  but, I am not getting the desired results! 
What I have tried is this (don't know what is wrong?)

```
data = data.point(lambda p: 1 if p < 127  else 0 ) # threshold, invert and normalize to 1
```

For example, when trying

```
print(np.array(data).max())
```

prints `True`.

However, converting the `PIL Image` to `numpy` array and then inverting it worked, as follows:

```
data = np.array(data.getdata(),
                np.uint8).reshape(data.size[1], data.size[0], 1)        
        maxG = data.max() # correcting the values of folder e, they do not match the other folders
        data = ( (maxG - data)/maxG ).astype('uint8') 
        tsfm = transforms.ToPILImage() #import torchvision.transforms as transforms
        data = tsfm(data)
```

I have tried both methods in a word recognition experiment, only the second one worked for me. Sadly, using the `point` function led to incorrect results.
Not sure what is the difference?

NB. The second method is extremely slow, so if this conversion could be done using the `point` function, that would be a great deal of help.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing *"normalisation"* and *"thresholding"*.

With *"thresholding"*, you make all values above or equal to a threshold equal to some high number and all values below the threshold equal to some low number. The only possible outcome for each pixel is either the high number or the low number - nothing in between. On a typical 8-bit image, you would threshold at 127, and all pixels would end up as either 0 or 255.

With *"normalisation"*, you constrain all values in the image between some new upper and some new lower limit - **or any value between**. So the outcome is a bunch of new pixels greater than the low limit and lower than the high limit, but evenly interpolated between the two. On a typical image, you might normalise all values to the range 0-255 and each pixel could end up with any value in that range.

Comment: I know exactly what normalization and what thresholding are. Maybe I did not explain the problem well. But thanks for your input! 
In a nutshell, I need to normalize the image(s) from [0, 255] to [0,1], and also need to invert the image(s). In fact, thresholding is a minor issue here and the second approach does not have it. 
My question, again, I really need to know why the $\point-function$ is not working as I expected?

Comment: The `point()` function isn't normalising correctly because it is an inverting threshold function which can only output 1 or 0, and not a normalising function which would be able to output fractional values in between.

Comment: @markStechell As I have text (binary) images, the normalization that results in real-valued outputs is not a concern. The normalization intended is 255 to 1, and 0 stays 0. If it is not a terminology dilemma, maybe we can call it mapping.